# How to return a view data using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-view

Hi friends the requirement is that using a stored procedure I should return all the value from a view.

Currently we are having a storedprocedure to return all the values from a table as given,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SuperGas_GetAllEmployees] 
    AS
BEGIN

SELECT [Employee ID]
      ,[First Name]
      ,[Last Name]
      ,[Group]
      ,[Location]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[DOJ]
      ,[Manager]
      ,[Projects]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[Extension]
  FROM [SuperGas].[dbo].[Employee]
END
```

We have created a view by joining two tables named ExpenseView as given,

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ExpenseView] AS
SELECT Emp.[Employee ID], Emp.[First Name],Emp.[Last Name],Emp.Manager, Ep.[Expense Type],Ep.[Expense Amount],Ep.[Expense Date]
FROM [Employee Expense] as Ep
FULL JOIN Employee as Emp
ON EP.[Employee ID] = Emp.[Employee ID]
```

Now the question here is like in the first stored procedure, how can I return all the columns of the above view (Expense) using a stored procedure.
We tried using the same way as the first procedure; however the View ExpenseView is not identified in the query.

History,

From my previous question I came to know, it is not good to use view with a Storedprocedure.

However our application is using the below c# code to get data from the Database using a stored Procedure,

```
string spName = "SuperGas_GetAllEmployees";

 DataSet ds = GetDatasetFromAdapter(spName);
```

Changing this needs extensive time and extra resources for the coding. Hence is there any way I can return the entire View (Like what we did in the given procedure SuperGas_GetAllEmployees for Tables) So that I can make use of current Code itself.

Thank you for all your Help

**Editing ....**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SuperGas_GetAllExpenseView] 
    AS
BEGIN

    SELECT [Employee ID]
      ,[First Name]
      ,[Last Name]
      ,[Manager]
      ,[Expense Type]
      ,[Expense Amount]
      ,[Expense Date]
  FROM [SuperGas].[dbo].[ExpenseView]
END

GO
```

Here I am getting error for the fields Expense Type, Expense Amount, Expense Date and for the view name ExpenseView

Please help me

Comment: Can you post the code for the Procedure you tried to create which selects from the view?

Comment: It **is** the same as for a table. What do you mean `the View ExpenseView is not identified in the query.`

Comment: Sure the same way I did Let me edit the question.

Comment: Why are you thinking this "From my previous question I came to know, it is not good to use view with a Storedprocedure"? There's no difference (ok, it is, but from the code point of view very small) between getting data set as a result of SQL query querying table or view and as a result of SP.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Btw, asking this way will not help you - I have a problem, please help me.

Comment: please find the updated question, @KarelFrajtak Yes that is why currently, I was asked to keep the C# code as it is. So I am forced to use a stored procedure for view as well.

Comment: yes, and I don't see the problem - the code seems to be working (your company is using it) and since you can't describe the error, I think the problem is in SP.

Comment: @Karel You are correct, C# code is just fine. Problem is with SP,I am getting the error Invalid object name for [SuperGas].[dbo].[ExpenseView]. I will not get the error if I am using any table name. Only for views getting the error.

Comment: The you are not executing the query in the database you're connected to - check the SP SQL query (copy it and try to execute it), try to remove all [SuperGas].[dbo] prefixes...

Comment: No luck. Here view is not at all Identified, By the way I created the view in the same Database, and if I execute the view I am getting the output correctly, However only problem when it comes to StoredProcedure.

Comment: @Karel, Thank you for your time, I apologize that it was my mistake, though I am getting error Invalid object, If I execute the procedure It will work, Since I got that errors I did not execute and checked. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Can anyone tell me how to close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ExpenseView] AS
```

Actually where the view is created? In your stored procedure you use `FROM [SuperGas].[dbo].[ExpenseView]`

Could you please ensure that the view is inside of `[SuperGas]`

Comment: Thank you for your time, I apologize that it was my mistake, though I am getting error Invalid object, If I execute the procedure It will work, Since I got that errors I did not execute and checked. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Can you tell me how to close this question?

Comment: @Jithu Well. Could you please vote up and accept my answer, if it helped you to find the error. I will vote to close the question. A total vote of 5 is needed to close your question.

Comment: I would love to, however I am unable to vote up the question since, I dont have a minimum reputation of 15. By the way I will accept your answer.